# what's up with "user2567"

Tags: discussion

I just forget his name -- but he is (used to be?) the LEADING reputation holder on Programmers.SE, and has asked such popular questions as:

[I'm a Subversion geek, why should I consider or not consider Mercurial or Git or any other DVCS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35074/im-a-subversion-geek-why-should-i-consider-or-not-consider-mercurial-or-git-or)

Why, then he is shown as "user2567"? And can someone help me recollect his name?

Comment: The user was [Pierre303](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/where-did-pierre-303-go-he-was-an-all-star)

Comment: And we're hoping that this "deletion" is only temporary and that, when he returns, all of his posts will be deanonymized. <- *Yes, that's the first time that I've ever used that word in a sentence.*

Comment: @JimG. Based on my conversations with him, its not happening.

Comment: @Rachel Users will come and go and as some step down, that leaves more room for new users to come in with fresh attitudes and diverse knowledge to leave their mark on Programmers and become the next generation of All Stars.  I can think of a number of such people.  Also it is important to look at things relatively too.  It is easy to accumulate a lot of rep when a site first starts out.  A few highly popular questions or answers and you have thousands of rep immediately.  Rep is a good indicator of an all star, but so are moderation participation, meta involvement and editing.

Comment: @maple_shaft: *It is easy to accumulate a lot of rep when a site first starts out. A few highly popular questions or answers and you have thousands of rep immediately.* - You're 100% right. I've actually seen this on another SE site. // *Rep is a good indicator of an all star, but so are moderation participation, meta involvement and editing.* - Right again, although I thought (perhaps most of us thought) that Pierre303 was a legitimate all-star.

Comment: @JimG. I want to be perfectly clear that I am not calling into question his "All Star" status in my eyes.  It is a shame that he decided to leave, I just wanted to point out that new users will step up and fill the void that others leave.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Yep. I know you weren't. // On a related note, I know that Programmers.SE can't be all things to all people, but I really regret the departure of some of our "All-Stars".

Answer (score 10):

The account has been deleted. Only the developers would be able to tell you what the person's name was - not that they are likely to though.

As content is provided under the [cc sa 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) when an account is deleted the posts the user made remain, but they are anonymised.

In very rare circumstances posts can be disassociated from an account, which will produce the same kind of post.

As there is no account, there is no profile page so there's no way to access all of their posts *(thanks to Walter for reminding me of that)*

Comment: Once the account has been deleted, no you cannot access their profile page and see all their posts.

Comment: If I recall right, manual disassociation changes the name to "anon", not to the userid-based name. That wouldn't be very anonymizing. :)